# How many analytic functions are there satisfying the given condition?

Tags: complex-analysis, complex-numbers

> How many analytic functions $f(z)$ are there in $\Omega$ with the property that $f(z)^2+3if(z)+4\equiv 0$ on $\Omega$ ?
>
> where, $\Omega$ is the whole complex plane with two co-ordinate axes removed.

I got two analytic functions $f:\Omega\to \mathbb C$ satisfying the given conditions which are $f(z)=i$ , $f(z)=-4i$.

But how I found all such functions ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Expanding on @Michael's answer, we'll first show that any such function $f(z)$ has to be locally constant. Taking derivatives, we get 
$$2 f(z) f'(z) + 3i f'(z) = f'(z) \left( 2 f(z) + 3i \right) = 0,$$
so at every point either $f'(z) = 0$ or $2f(z) + 3i = 0$.  Substituting $f(z) = -\frac{3i}{2}$ into the original equation, gives
$$
-\frac{9}{4} + \frac{9}{2} + 4 \not= 0,
$$
so we can never have $f(z) = -\frac{3i}{2}$. Therefore, the only possibilities are the locally constant functions (because $f'(z) = 0$) which satisfy the equation 
$$f(z)^2 + 3i f(z) + 4 = (f(z) - i)(f(z) + 4i) = 0,$$
so their values have to be $i$ or $-4i$ on each connected component of $\Omega$. This gives a total of $2^4 = 16$ possible functions.

Comment: So what is the total number of functions ?

Comment: Well you have 4 connected components and 2 possibilities for each component...

Answer (score 5):

$\Omega$ has four regions.  Each region may be $i$ or $-4i$.

Comment: Analytic functions are continuous on their domains.  This function can only take two values, so it must be constant on any open set.  But the function doesn't have to be continuous across the coordinate axes.

Comment: Call the regions $A,B,C,D$.  The set $\{A,B,C,D\}$ has sixteen subsets.  Each subset has a function.  For example, the subset $\{A,C\}$ has the function which equals $i$ in $A$ and $C$, and $-4i$ in the other regions.